# Podfile.lock modified during installation of pods on build server

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

My React Native app is being built on several macOS machines. Recently I faced an issue on one of them as the build started to fail during pods installation.

```bash
pod install --deployment
```

On all the servers (except the problematic one) the above command successfully installs the required pods and the Podfile.lock file remains untouched, but on one of them I get:

```bash
[!] There were changes to the podfile in deployment mode:
M hermes-engine
```

The Podfile.lock is indeed modified and contains the following:

```bash
hermes-engine:
  :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-engine/hermes-engine.podspec"
  :tag: ''
```

while the original content of the file is:

```bash
hermes-engine:
  :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-engine/hermes-engine.podspec"
  :tag: hermes-2023-08-07-RNv0.72.4-813b2def12bc9df02654b3e3653ae4a68d0572e0
```

What may be the reason for removing the `tag` value from this file during `pod install`?

**UPDATE:**

All the build servers have the same tools installed:

| tool | Mac1 (fine) | Mac2 (fine) | Mac3 (problematic) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OS | macOS 13.6 (ARM64) | macOS 13.3.1 (X64) | macOS 13.4.1 (ARM64) |
| Shell | 5.9 | 5.9 | 5.9 |
| Node | 18.17.1 | 18.17.0 | 18.17.1 |
| Yarn | 1.22.19 | 1.22.19 | 1.22.19 |
| npm | 9.6.7 | 9.6.7 | 9.6.7 |
| CocoaPods | 1.12.1 | 1.12.1 | 1.12.1 |
| Xcode | 14.3.1 | 14.3 | 14.3.1 |
| Java | 17.0.7 | 17.0.7 | 17.0.8 |
| Ruby | 2.6.10 | 2.6.10 | 2.6.10 |

I have also cleared the CocoaPods cache from all machines but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a similar issue in the past, and it took some effort to identify the root cause. Ultimately, the problem stemmed from differing versions of tools installed on our servers.

To diagnose this issue, you can compare the versions of the following tools using the terminal:

1. Xcode Version: `xcodebuild -version`
2. Cocoapods Version: `pod --version`
3. Node.js Version: `node -v`

Also check cocoapods-patch version: `gem list cocoapods-patch`

By comparing these versions, you are likely to uncover discrepancies. This underscores the importance of maintaining a standardized toolset for larger projects. Typically, such standards are documented in a README.md file, and it's crucial for all team members to adhere to this common toolset to ensure consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Btw. you can run `npx react-native info` to get a complete report about the system and tools. It took me a while to make the OS and tools aligned. Unfortunately, the build still fails on the problematic MacOS server. I updated my question with a complete list of system info.